# what's the difference of setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); setVisibility(0);

Tags: android, android-layout

I met a strange issue, when i set a textview visibility as
`text.setVisibility(0)`; I cannot hide this textview. But after i update the code to `text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`, the textview is hidden...

I have no idea,  why this happened....

Comment: @RajaReddyP You are also suggested to see the link I given in my answer.

Comment: @Frankenstein your link not working..

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You got misconcept I think,

0 stands for VISIBLE..You can check here **[Developer Doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#VISIBLE)**

> ```
> 0 is for VISIBLE
> 4 is for INVISIBLE 
> 8 is for GONE
> ```

So nothing going wrong in your case,Its working properly as per you passed the parameter.

Comment: You can link to the online docs... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#VISIBLE

Comment: +1 nice @aromero ..brilliant work..I just didn't see that I am giving link from another browser..thanks

Answer (score 7):

That's because `0` means `VISIBLE`. `INVISIBLE` is `4`. These are constant values defined in [`View`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html):

- [`View.VISIBLE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#VISIBLE)
- [`View.INVISIBLE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE)
- [`View.GONE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE)

Answer (score 2):

Simple because `INVISIBLE` has the value 4.

So,Try this code `text.setVisibility(4);`

Will work.

Comment: Works, but would be really poor coding style. The constants are there to be used; this is the code OP should try:
`text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

Answer (score 0):

The int is the problem

DOC [OFFICIAL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3avisibility)

android:visibility

Controls the initial visibility of the view.

Must be one of the following constant values.

Constant    Value   Description
visible         0   Visible on screen; the default value.
invisible   1   Not displayed, but taken into account during layout 
gone            2   Completely hidden, as if the view had not been added.

This corresponds to the global attribute resource symbol visibility.
Related Methods

```
setVisibility(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

`View.GONE` = setVisibility(8)

`View.INVISIBLE` = setVisibility(4)

`View.VISIBLE` = setVisibility(0)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since [another user already posted that solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8636162/3169238). If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up once you have enough reputation